# Calculating length of a street with Google Maps

Tags: maps, endpoint

I have to calculate length of a street with Google Maps API. I've already searched for "start and end point of a street", etc... there are no good solutions.

What I need in example:
1. Look for "Ludwigstraße, München"
2. Get length of this street in meter (miles or whatever)

Does anyone have a good idea or any other method how to manage this? Perhaps there is a possibility to make this via overlays?

Answer (score 0):

If you had start and end point of street already, try to use google map api distance matrix, that service will return the distance between start and end point.[enter link description here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/)